# VBA Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, excel, teradata, vba

For some reason it's returning run-time error 3021 , SQL string is working ok when trying in Terada SQLAssistant.

Can someone give me hint what I'm doing wrong ?

Value in cell equal to John Doe

```
Dim ConcatSQL As String

ConcatSQL = Sheets("LogIn").Cells(8, 3).Value



QueryA = "select *  from database.table WHERE Name = " & ConcatSQL & "   

 cmdSQLData.CommandText = QueryA
cmdSQLData.CommandType = adCmdText
cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 0
MsgBox (QueryA)

Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()
Row = 1
rs.MoveFirst ' it's falling here 
 Do While (rs.EOF = False And rs.BOF = False)
```

Comment: Try `QueryA = "select *  from database.table WHERE Name = " & ConcatSQL` (remove the last `& "`)

Comment: This same issue as before run-time error 3021 Either BOF or EOF is true , or the current record haseen deleted.

Comment: QueryA = "select *  from database.table WHERE " & chr(34) & Name & chr(34) & " = '" & ConcatSQL & "'" - assuming your column name is actually Name. Otherwise: QueryA = "select *  from database.table WHERE Column_Name = '" & ConcatSQL & "'"

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for the error is that field `Name` is a reserved word in Teradata, so you should use `"Name"` (using double quotes) instead

```
QueryA = "select *  from database.table WHERE " & Chr(34) & "Name" & Chr(34) & " = " & ConcatSQL
```

Comment: Teradata uses double quotes rather than brackets.

Comment: @DavidCram you are right https://community.teradata.com/t5/General/How-to-use-reserved-key-words-as-column-names/td-p/55983

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()
If Err.Number<>0 Then
  MsgBox(Err.Description)
End If
```

And post the output? Also can you post the output of QueryA.